# Unitary derivative for plane curves

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, derivatives

Let $\mathbf{r}:I\to\mathbb{R}^2$, where $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is an open interval, be a continuous function that is not constant on any subinterval $J\subseteq I$ such that at each point $t\in I$ the following thow limits exists:

$\frac{D\mathbf{r}}{Dt^+}(t_0)=\lim\limits_{t\to t^{+}_0} \frac{\mathbf{r}(t)-\mathbf{r}(t_0)}{||\mathbf{r}(t)-\mathbf{r}(t_0)||}$.

$\frac{D\mathbf{r}}{Dt^-}(t_0)=\lim\limits_{t\to t^{-}_0} \frac{\mathbf{r}(t)-\mathbf{r}(t_0)}{||\mathbf{r}(t)-\mathbf{r}(t_0)||}$.

Are the following sets countable?

$U=\{t\in I\ |\ \frac{D\mathbf{r}}{Dt^+}(t)\neq\pm\frac{D\mathbf{r}}{Dt^-}(t)\}$, and

$I=\{t\in I\ |\ \frac{D\mathbf{r}}{Dt^+}(t)=\frac{D\mathbf{r}}{Dt^-}(t)\}$.